# No SQL Model in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, nosql

I'd like to create a Model as following:

```
class User extends AppModel {
        var $name = 'User';
        var $useTable = false;
        var $primaryKey = 'user_id';
        var $hasOne = 'Profile'; 

}
```

but, the Model User is saved as No SQL.

How can I use that model?
BTW this model is readonly.
(EDIT/CREATE USER are done by another functions(no cake))

I'm assuming crypted cookie datastore

Comment: What kind of No-SQL database are you using?

Comment: Actually, the Middleware is not decided yet. Probably I'll decided memcached or memcached compatibleｓ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at example on how to using MongoDb with CakePHP. Read Mark Story's post about that in http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-mongodb-with-cakephp.

Comment: Thank you for replying , If you could recommend Crypted Cookie DataSource I'm so happy